# No module named 'glob2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.1, using Python3 and trying to import glob2 module in my python code but it gave me this error:

> ImportError: No module named 'glob2'

I installed glob2 with:

> sudo pip install glob2

and also:

> sudo apt-get install python-pip sudo pip install glob2

but none of them worked for me, any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps try `sudo pip3 install glob2`? I'm not too familiar with Linux, but my little experience is telling me `glob2` is being installed under Python 2 instead

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right, I used pip3 and it solved my problem!